# Xcode: When my image rotates to a non-90 degree angle, it shifts the location

Tags: xcode, image, rotation

I have a program where I want to have an image that can be manually rotated using one of the following options: Left 1 or 5 degrees, right 1 or 5 degrees, or set a specific degree to rotate to. All of the mechanics work fine, but whenever the image is rotated to a degree (not 0,90,180,270, or 360) the entire image shifts down-right. It keeps doing it until it hits a 45 degree angle, then starts shifting back to the starting position, and I cannot figure out why. I have tried many fixes, but none of them have any effect.

h.file:

```
    //
//  AirNavViewController.h
//  Compass
//
//  Created by JDS on 5/26/14.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 THE OHIO STATE UNIVERSITY. All rights reserved.
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface AirNavViewController : UIViewController {


    int Rotation;
    float degrees;


}

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *Compass;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *RotationLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISlider *DegreesSlider;

    -(IBAction)Left5:(id)sender;
    -(IBAction)Left1:(id)sender;
    -(IBAction)Right1:(id)sender;
    -(IBAction)Right5:(id)sender;
    -(IBAction)SliderMoved:(id)sender;
    -(IBAction)CustomRotate:(id)sender;


@end
```

m.file:

```
//
//  AirNavViewController.m
//  Compass
//
//  Created by JDS on 5/26/14.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 THE OHIO STATE UNIVERSITY. All rights reserved.
//

#import "AirNavViewController.h"

@interface AirNavViewController ()

@end

@implementation AirNavViewController


    @synthesize Compass, RotationLabel, DegreesSlider;


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    RotationLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"0°"];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


-(IBAction)SliderMoved:(id)sender{

    degrees = DegreesSlider.value;
    RotationLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.0f°", degrees];

}


-(IBAction)CustomRotate:(id)sender{

    Compass.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(degrees*M_PI/180);
    Rotation = degrees;

}


-(IBAction)Left5:(id)sender{

    Rotation = Rotation-5;

    if (Rotation > 359) {Rotation = Rotation-360;}
    if (Rotation < 0) {Rotation = Rotation+360;}

    Compass.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation((Rotation*M_PI)/180);

}


-(IBAction)Left1:(id)sender{

    Rotation = Rotation-1;

    if (Rotation > 359) {Rotation = Rotation-360;}
    if (Rotation < 0) {Rotation = Rotation+360;}

    Compass.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation((Rotation*M_PI)/180);

}


-(IBAction)Right1:(id)sender{

    Rotation = Rotation+1;

    if (Rotation > 359) {Rotation = Rotation-360;}
    if (Rotation < 0) {Rotation = Rotation+360;}

    Compass.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation((Rotation*M_PI)/180);
}


-(IBAction)Right5:(id)sender{

    Rotation = Rotation+5;

    if (Rotation > 359) {Rotation = Rotation-360;}
    if (Rotation < 0) {Rotation = Rotation+360;}

    Compass.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation((Rotation*M_PI)/180);
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, some code comments.

Remove the `@synthesize` code. It is no longer needed.
Properties and iVars should begin with a lowercase letter.

Anyway, from the lack of layout code I'm guessing that you are using AutoLayout.

In which case there will be constraints on the image view that will specify...

Distance from top and distance from left. (or bottom, or right).

The way these work is they take the minimum enclosing (non rotated) rect of the image view and position this rect so that it conforms to the constraints.

Because the enclosing rect grows bigger when rotating up to 45degrees the image looks like it is moving.

You can change the constraints to say something like...

Align the centre to the centre of the screen or something like that.

Comment: Ok, I understand what you mean, but how would I tell it to align like that?

Comment: Well. you're using AutoLayout. So instead of aligning "left edge" or "top edge" or "leading edge" etc... Use "Center X" and "Center Y".

Comment: Ok, I found the alignment tools, and Aligned the Center coordinates, however that created a new problem. The image is now scaled up far too big, but it does rotate properly. I cannot figure out why simply aligning the center x and y coordinates is causing it.

Comment: You now need to set the height and width. If you don't constrain the height and width then the image view will use its "intrinsic content size" i.e. the height and width of the image you put in it. Add height and width constraints to the image view and it should fix your problem.